# Unsupported gRPC frame flag: 1 in response of Cloud Endpoints OpenAPI for Cloud Run with ESPv2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc-python, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have deployed a service in GCP cloud endpoint and in backend calling a GRPC service. In GRPC service I have taken a string type param in proto. When I get big string in response I receive error "Unsupported gRPC frame flag: 1" in response from endpoint service otherwise its giving proper response.

```
{
    "message": "Unsupported gRPC frame flag: 1",
    "code": 502
}
```

Is there any size limit of string in transcoding from GRPC to HTTP ?
If I am calling GRPC API from python client then its working fine.

My proto file is -

```
message  ListResponse{
  int32 responseCode = 1;
  string messageDetail = 2;
}
```

I have run the following command

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc \
    --include_imports \
    --include_source_info \
    --proto_path=./proto \
    --descriptor_set_out=./endpoint/api_descriptor.pb \
    --python_out=./generated_pb2 \
    --grpc_python_out=./generated_pb2 \
    message.proto msgbody.proto attachment.proto
```

And my configuration file is as follows api_config.yaml:

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3
name: CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME
title: gatewayendpoint for grpc
apis:
  - name: com.example.Message
usage:
  rules:
  - selector: com.example.message.Message.List
    allow_unregistered_calls: true
backend:
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      address: grpc://GRPC_HOST_ADDRESS:50052
      protocol: "h2"
```

For smaller string upto length 20 its giving proper response. When I increase length over 25 characters its giving error "Unsupported gRPC frame flag: 1".

Comment: Possibly. Logs? Does it work with smaller strings? What size strings cause the problem? What then are the overall message sizes? Consider including the proto and the service descriptor

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes its working fine for smaller string length upto 20. I have updated the question.
Log is showing like following when I increase string length.

**E0601 06:06:20.116 24 src/envoy/http/service_control/client_cache.cc:161] [24][filter]Failed to call report, error: PERMISSION_DENIED:Calling Google Service Control API failed with: 403 and body: \010\007\022#The caller does not have permission, str body: \010\007\022#The caller does not have permission**

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Very curious. Your `backend.rules.address` should be the Cloud Run service's 443 port not 50052 so I'm surprised it works. It took me time to configure the `google.api.Service` and it was some time ago that I last touched mine but, I have `usage.rules.selector` and `bakend.rules.selector` as `"*"` though I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: @DazWilkin **backend.rules.address** is the address of my GRPC server hosted and thats port is 50052. I am triggering REST call to Cloud Run and Cloud Run in backend is calling GRPC API whose port is 50052. There should be some configuration of string length in api_config.yaml but I am not getting anything such in documentation.

Comment: Cloud Run proxies the backend service to port 443.